# Istio - weighted routing for TLS routes

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We have two Microservices A and B. A calls B through the istio-proxy side car.

We created a Virtual service. Please see below for the yaml

After creating the virtual service, when we check the routes in pod A using this command `istioctl proxy-config routes a-75768cc7bc-ghzsr -o json`, we do NOT see weighted routes

If we replace tls with http, weighted routes are added. Can we use weighted routes with tls ?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: b
  namespace: default  
spec:
  hosts:
  - b
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: b
        subset: v1
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: b
        subset: v2
      weight: 50
```

Adding service definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:          
 labels:        
  svc: b
 name: b
 namespace: default      
spec:
  clusterIP: x.x.x.x
  ports:
  - name: https-b
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    svc: b
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Adding Destination rule,

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:  
  name: b
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: b
  subsets:
  - labels:
      version: v1
    name: v1
  - labels:
      version: v2
    name: v2
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that Service definition has port name with `http-service-a`?

From [VirtualService documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService), HTTP and TLS have different spec.

`http`

> HTTP routes will be applied to platform service ports named ‘http-’/‘http2-’/‘grpc-*’, gateway ports with protocol HTTP/HTTP2/GRPC/ TLS-terminated-HTTPS and service entry ports using HTTP/HTTP2/GRPC protocols.

`tls`

> TLS routes will be applied to platform service ports named ‘https-’, ‘tls-’, unterminated gateway ports using HTTPS/TLS protocols (i.e. with “passthrough” TLS mode) and service entry ports using HTTPS/TLS protocols.

Given the above difference, it could explain the different behaviour.

Which version of Istio are you using? It would be good to see K8s definitions as well.

Comment: Istio version is 1.6.1. I have edited the question to add service definition

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the services involved here, the Service definition in question should be B, as that's the destination. Also, do you have DestinationRules?

Comment: Edited the question to add destination rule.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure at this point, but you seem to have no configuration to indicate TLS setup. Have you tried out adding some [traffic policy and client TLS settings](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings)? What kind of TLS routing do you require in the cluster, is it Isito based mTLS, or some other custom setup? You may also find some more details by running `istioctl analyze -A`